# How to find a devices objectID in AzureAD/ Endoint manager?

Tags: office365, azure, intune

See title. I can find the Azure AD Devuce ID and the Intune device ID, but I need the objectID to manually add a device to a group.

Answer (score 0):

[Get-AzureADDevice](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddevice?view=azureadps-2.0)
Returns ObjectIDs